# Mongo slow startup after upgrade to 4.2.5

Tags: mongodb

I have upgraded the MongoDB replica set, which consists of 3 members, from 4.0.11 to 4.2.5. After upgrading, startup lasts about 5 minutes. Before upgrading it was instant. It is related to oplog size, because I tested with dropping oplog on new mongo 4.2 and startup was instant. 
Max oplog size was 25GB, I decreased it to 5GB and the startup is still slow. Mongo db is on AWS with EBS standard disks. However mongo worked well until this upgrade.
Do you have any idea what can cause slow startup?
I tried with changing following 3 WiredTiger default eviction parameters:

```
storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.configString:
"eviction_dirty_target=60,
eviction_dirty_trigger=80,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4)"
```

Now mongo is starting immediately. Is it safe to set eviction_dirty_target and eviction_dirty_trigger values like this? Default is : eviction_dirty_target (default 5%) and eviction_dirty_trigger (default 20%). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the server logs, they'll say what the database is doing.